# struct with typedef names

Tags: struct, typedef

In a book I found a more complex program that I condense in the following two parts:

### main.c

```
int main()
{
    struct list_t;  // Note 1
    struct list_t* list_malloc(); // Note 2
    struct list_t* list1 = list_malloc();
    return 0;
}
```

### other.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int* items;
} list_t;

list_t* list_malloc()
{
    return (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
}
```

The two programs are compiled and assembled fine with a recent gcc under Linux Debian.

This is a different schema than the more usual one with the `typedef` on a header file.

I am trying to understand:

1. Why in **main()**  `list_t` must be preceded with `struct`, as `list_t` is already a `struct`, and in **other.c** it is actually used in the signature of a function.
2. Where in the standard (any about C) is this construction described?
3. Why line with *Note 1* is correct? It seems actually not needed to successfully compile the program and `extern` is not correct here. Where in the standard?
4. In line with *Note 2* `extern` is correct (but not needed). What's different?
5. Why in **main()**, if `union` is used instead of `struct` the compiler does not complain and the program runs. UB maybe?

BTW in the original sources line with *Note 1* and all the prototypes where in a header file and the idea was to hide better the content of **other.c**.

Comment: #1: This is a C vs C++ difference.  In C++, `struct list_t {...};` automatically creates a type `list_t`.  In C, that does not happen.  The name of the type is `struct list_t`.

Comment: #3: Because you can have a pointless declaration statement.  You can write `int;` or `float;`.  This is exactly the same.  It is useless.

Comment: The book where I took this code was about doing some OOP in C and the compiler I used is gcc, not g++.

Comment: #4: This is just a prototype.  If not found locally, it will be an unresolved external and it's up to the linker to find it.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  The `struct list_t` is a forward reference.  It tells the compiler "there is a structure called `list_t` somewhere, but you don't need to know what's inside it."  As long as you just work with pointers to it, and don't try to use members, it all works.

Comment: OK for the forward reference, can you identify where in the standard a forward reference is described with a *typedef* identifier? And why if `struct` changed to `union` is not marked as an error (question 5)? ty

Comment: Because those two types are NOT RELATED.  `main` is treating that type like a `void *`.   It doesn't care whether there really is a `struct list_t` defined anywhere in the whole project.  You could call it `struct blahblah_t` in `main` and it would still compile and execute just fine.  You could make it `int *` and it would work.  It's just an anonymous pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not every C language book, or OOP book is useful ... it looks like yours demonstrates three notable points:

1. A type can be defined independently in multiple C files - without a single source of truth - this even can work, if the coder is careful and these unrelated definitions are 'compatible enough'.
2. Declarations of types and functions (prototypes) can be placed inside a function. You need to pay attention to distinguish a function declaration from a call. Function forward declarations can go without `extern`. Like in #1, multiple functions within one C file can have independent declaration of same things.
3. A struct type can be declared without the body, such incomplete declaration can be used where the compiler does not need to know about the struct members.
   This is a feature, it can be used to emulate "abstract types" in C, which are accessed only via a pointer.

Points 1 and 2 remind that C is not a 'safe' language; it provides the programmers enough rope to shoot themselves in the leg.

*A bonus to #2: `struct list_t* list_malloc()` is not quite a function prototype in modern C, because it misses parameters. A complete prototype is `struct list_t* list_malloc(void)`. Again, a programmer can get away with this if they are careful. In C++ this would be a correct prototype though.*